# What is the default license for solidity code released to the blockchain?

Tags: solidity

What is the default license for solidity code released to the blockchain?
Is there such a thing?

I'm just wondering because i thought the idea of smart contracts is to release the source code, so people can make informed decisions whether to use said contract or not.
Even if the source code is not revealed, it seems to me that it is in the best interest of a lot of people to try and decompile it.
One way or another most smart contract's code will be available somewhere somehow and now the question: what license applies to this code?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any sort of default license that applies to smart contract code.